# can not build a Container using a Dockerfile

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-compute-engine, docker-machine

I am working on VM instances from the Google Cloud Platform and I am using Docker for the first time, so please bear with me. I am trying to follow steps to build a container because it is supposed to be a certain way for a project. I am stuck here:

1. Create the directory named ~/keto (~/ refers to your home directory)
2. Create a file ~/keto/Dockerfile
3. Add the following content to ~/keto/Dockerfile and save

```docker
#Pull the keto/ssh image from Docker hub
FROM keto/ssh:latest 

# Create a user and password with environment variables
ENV SSH_USERNAME spock

ENV SSH_PASSWORD Vulcan

#Copy a ssh public key from ~/keto/id_rsa.pub to spock .ssh/authorized_keys
COPY ./id_rsa.pub /home/spock/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I was able to Pull the keto/ssh image from the Docker hub
with no issues, but my problem is that I am unable to create the directory and I am also stuck when it comes to creating the environment variable. Can anyone guide me to what is the correct approach to:

A-build a directory and B- after I am done with the directory to create environment variables I would really appreciate it a lot. thank you

Comment: Have you installed Docker? Try running all the commands starting with sudo

Answer (score 0):

```
#Pull the keto/ssh image from Docker hub
FROM keto/ssh:latest 
# Create a user and password with environment variables
ENV SSH_USERNAME=spock
ENV SSH_PASSWORD=Vulcan
# Create keto directory:
RUN mkdir ~/keto
#Copy a ssh public key from ~/keto/id_rsa.pub to spock .ssh/authorized_keys
ADD ./id_rsa.pub /home/spock/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You may find useful the [Docker’s official documentation on how to create a Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-2-create-a-dockerfile) or to check how [ENV variable](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) has to be set.
I recommend always having a look at Dockerfile's hub, for this case is [keto's ssh](https://hub.docker.com/r/keto/ssh) because it usually contains some guidance about the image we are going to build.